# How to group duplicate records and set new columns/ values based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates

I would like to group duplicate records by the column **[FIELD]** and add new columns based on the given conditions.

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST](
    [TYPE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SECTION] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FIELD] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [InREPO] [nvarchar](255) NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST]
           ([TYPE]
           ,[SECTION]
           ,[FIELD]
           ,[InREPO])
     VALUES
           ('NDA','Info','Counterparty','TRUE'),
           ('NDA','Info','Country','TRUE'),
           ('NDA','Action','Region','FALSE'),
           ('CIS','Info','Counterparty','TRUE'),
           ('CIS','Action','Country','FALSE'),
           ('CIS','Action','Region','TRUE'),
           ('CIS','Hidden','Address','FALSE')
```

| TYPE | SECTION | FIELD | InREPO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NDA | Info | Counterparty | TRUE |
| NDA | Info | Country | TRUE |
| NDA | Action | Region | FALSE |
| CIS | Info | Counterparty | TRUE |
| CIS | Action | Country | FALSE |
| CIS | Action | Region | TRUE |
| CIS | Hidden | Address | FALSE |

**Expected result:**

| FIELD | NDA | NDA_SECTION | NDA_InREPO | CIS | CIS_SECTION | CIS_InREPO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Counterparty | TRUE | Info | TRUE | TRUE | Info | TRUE |
| Country | TRUE | Info | TRUE | TRUE | Action | FALSE |
| Region | TRUE | Action | FALSE | TRUE | Action | TRUE |
| Address | FALSE | n/a | n/a | TRUE | Hidden | FALSE |

**What I have so far:**

```
    SELECT [FIELD],
       CASE
           WHEN [TYPE] like 'NDA' THEN
               'TRUE'
           ELSE
               'FALSE'
       END AS [NDA],
       CASE
           WHEN [TYPE] like 'NDA' THEN
               [SECTION]
           ELSE
               'n/a'
       END AS [NDA_SECTION],
       CASE
           WHEN [TYPE] like 'NDA' THEN
               [InREPO]
           ELSE
               'n/a'
       END AS [NDA_InREPO],
       CASE
           WHEN [TYPE] like 'CIS' THEN
               'TRUE'
           ELSE
               'FALSE'
       END AS [CIS],
       CASE
           WHEN [TYPE] like 'CIS' THEN
               [SECTION]
           ELSE
               'n/a'
       END AS [CIS_SECTION],
       CASE
           WHEN [TYPE] like 'CIS' THEN
               [InREPO]
           ELSE
               'n/a'
       END AS [CIS_InREPO]
FROM [TEST]
```

**Current Result:**

| FIELD | NDA | NDA_SECTION | NDA_InREPO | CIS | CIS_SECTION | CIS_InREPO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Counterparty | TRUE | Info | TRUE | FALSE | n/a | n/a |
| Country | TRUE | Info | TRUE | FALSE | n/a | n/a |
| Region | TRUE | Action | FALSE | FALSE | n/a | n/a |
| Counterparty | FALSE | n/a | n/a | TRUE | Info | TRUE |
| Country | FALSE | n/a | n/a | TRUE | Action | FALSE |
| Region | FALSE | n/a | n/a | TRUE | Action | TRUE |
| Address | FALSE | n/a | n/a | TRUE | Hidden | FALSE |

Any ideas on how to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Aside... when dealing with `nchar` and `nvarchar` data types be sure to use National character literals where the string literal is prefixed with an uppercase `N`. Failing to do so means your string literal is interpreted according to your database's default collation and can cause loss of characters. Compare the output of `select 'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ' as [Default collation], N'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ' as [National character literal];` to see what this matters.

Comment: SELECT ... FROM CurrentTables JOIN (SELECT A TYPE, B Some, C Field3 UNION SELECT B TYPE, B Some, CC Field3 UNION etcc) x ON TYPE etccc

Comment: I haven't time to take this further - but consider using some form of self-join e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/rToJIzRA

Comment: btw: I cannot see the image (due to security policy) - please avoid images unless they are essential - a text table would work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add `GROUP BY` on column `[FIELD]`, then apply `MAX` aggregate function on the other columns.

This is modified version of your query, I've added `GROUP BY`, `MAX` function and replaced `CASE` expression with MS SQL's IFF function for shorter query.

```
SELECT [FIELD],
       MAX(IIF([TYPE] LIKE 'NDA', 'TRUE', 'FALSE')) AS [NDA],
       COALESCE(MAX(IIF([TYPE] LIKE 'NDA', [SECTION], NULL)), 'n/a') AS [NDA_SECTION],
       COALESCE(MAX(IIF([TYPE] LIKE 'NDA', [InREPO], NULL)), 'n/a') AS [NDA_InREPO],
       MAX(IIF([TYPE] LIKE 'CIS', 'TRUE', 'FALSE')) AS [CIS],
       COALESCE(MAX(IIF([TYPE] LIKE 'CIS', [SECTION], NULL)), 'n/a') AS [CIS_SECTION],
       COALESCE(MAX(IIF([TYPE] LIKE 'CIS', [InREPO], NULL)), 'n/a') AS [CIS_InREPO]
FROM [TEST]
GROUP BY [FIELD];
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0dy8LK9F)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a temporary table to store the distinct values for the column FIELD and the do a left outer join on the original table for the each of the values on the column TYPE, from there you can do a CASE WHEN or ISNULL expression for each field based on type.

```
DECLARE @Fields TABLE (Field NVARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @Fields (Field)
SELECT DISTINCT Field
FROM Test

SELECT f.Field,
    CASE WHEN nda.Field IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS NDA,
    ISNULL(nda.Section, 'n/a') AS NDA_SECTION,
    ISNULL(nda.InREPO, 'n/a') AS NDA_InREPO,
    CASE WHEN cis.Field IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS CIS,
    ISNULL(cis.Section, 'n/a') AS CIS_SECTION,
    ISNULL(cis.InREPO, 'n/a') AS CIS_InREPO
FROM @Fields f
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Test nda ON nda.Field = f.Field
        AND nda.[Type] = 'NDA'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Test cis ON cis.Field = f.Field
        AND cis.[Type] = 'CIS'
```